# Blockquotes should be formatted to support bullet points and numbered lists

Tags: support, markdown, blockquote

I was proposing an idea on a [MA.meta](http://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com), and I noticed that you cannot use bullet points inside a blockquote. To show what I mean, here are some images:

**Part of the original post I was trying to quote**
[image: Part of the original post I was trying to quote]

**My post on MA.meta**
[image: My post on MA.meta]

Notice that the bullet points are outside the blockquote. This is frustrating, because I don't want to have to change the quote at all, then it's not really a quote. Should blockquotes have closing tags as well or have a different markup symbol? Even when I use `<blockquote></blockquote>` bullet points aren't recognized; they turn out like this:
[image: blockquotes not allowing bullet points]

This is an issue, because

A. It looks bad

B. It's technically not a quote anymore

C. It takes away the entire emphatic purpose of bullet points in the first place

Comment: You can definitely use lists in blockquotes. You probably formatted it incorrectly, but we cannot look at that without the actual text you used. Screenshots do not help here.

Comment: @animuson as shown in wiz's answer, the "correct" formatting would take a very long time with longer lists.

Comment: @LemmyX Catija's answer says it only needs the first bulletpoint blockquoted

Comment: This is phrased more like a feature request or bug report than a support request... you might want to rephrase it to ask how to do it?

Comment: Also check the [markdown editing help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#advanced-blockquotes):

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They work just fine, you just need a bit of help on how the formatting works:

> For example:
>
> - Trust Level
> - Confidence in advice given
> - Formal vs informal relationship
> - Things you talk about

You write it like this:

```
> For example:

> - Trust Level
- Confidence in advice given
- Formal vs informal relationship
- Things you talk about
```

I'm guessing what you did was start the bullets after the "For example" with a single line break rather than a double break:

> For example:
>   - Trust Level
>   - Confidence in advice given
>   - Formal vs informal relationship
>   - Things you talk about

```
> For example:
> - Trust Level
- Confidence in advice given
- Formal vs informal relationship
- Things you talk about
```

To be clear... this doesn't relate to quotes at all because the problem (if this is how you did it) is the double space is required - even without the quote, it breaks:

For example: 
- Trust Level
- Confidence in advice given
- Formal vs informal relationship
- Things you talk about